# How do you make a GET request in Rust?

Tags: http, get, rust

I noticed that Rust doesn't have a builtin library to deal with HTTP, it only has a `net` module that deals with raw IP and TCP protocols.

I need to take a `&str` of the URL, make a HTTP GET request, and if successful return either a `String` or `&str` that corresponds to the HTML or JSON or other response in string form.

It would look something like:

```
use somelib::http;

let response = http::get(&"http://stackoverflow.com");
match response {
    Some(suc) => suc,
    None => panic!
}
```

Comment: Have you tried googling for http crates? For example, [this might work for you](https://github.com/alexcrichton/curl-rust).

Comment: This kind of question is off-topic on Stack Overflow, so it likely will be closed. If you haven't found your answer by then, I invite you to check the Rust tag wiki [Getting Help](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) section which details other venues for open-ended questions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Take a look at [Hyper](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper).

Sending a GET request is as simple as this.

```
let client = Client::new();

let res = client.get("http://example.domain").send().unwrap();
assert_eq!(res.status, hyper::Ok);
```

You can find more examples in the [documentation](https://hyper.rs/hyper/v0.10.5/hyper/client/index.html).

**Edit**:
It seems that [Hyper](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper) got a bit more complicated since they started to use [Tokio](https://tokio.rs/). Here is updated version.

```
extern crate futures;
extern crate hyper;
extern crate tokio_core;

use std::io::{self, Write};
use futures::{Future, Stream};
use hyper::Client;
use tokio_core::reactor::Core;


fn main() {
    let mut core = Core::new().unwrap();
    let client = Client::new(&core.handle());

    let uri = "http://httpbin.org/ip".parse().unwrap();
    let work =
        client.get(uri).and_then(|res| {
            println!("Response: {}", res.status());

            res.body().for_each(|chunk| {
                io::stdout()
                    .write_all(&chunk)
                    .map_err(From::from)
            })
        });
    core.run(work).unwrap();
}
```

And here are the required dependencies.

```
[dependencies]
futures = "0.1"
hyper = "0.11"
tokio-core = "0.1"
```

Comment: This no longer works, since `hyper::Client::new` takes some handle argument.

Answer (score 20):

The current best practice for this particular problem is to use the [`reqwest`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/*/reqwest/fn.get.html) crate, as specified [in the Rust Cookbook](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/rust-cookbook/web/clients/requests.html). This code is slightly adapted from the cookbook to run standalone:

```
extern crate reqwest; // 0.9.18

use std::io::Read;

fn run() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let mut res = reqwest::get("http://httpbin.org/get")?;
    let mut body = String::new();
    res.read_to_string(&mut body)?;

    println!("Status: {}", res.status());
    println!("Headers:\n{:#?}", res.headers());
    println!("Body:\n{}", body);

    Ok(())
}
```

As the cookbook mentions, this code will be executed synchronously.

See also:

- [How can I perform parallel asynchronous HTTP GET requests with reqwest?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51044467/155423)

Comment: Unfortunately reqwest requires OpenSSL so not good if you are doing cross compiling

Comment: Work for me in rust 1.75

Answer (score 6):

Try to go for reqwest:

```
extern crate reqwest;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let mut res = reqwest::get("https://httpbin.org/headers")?;

    // copy the response body directly to stdout
    std::io::copy(&mut res, &mut std::io::stdout())?;

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: An [answer that suggests reqwest already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45623133/155423). Please be very clear about what benefit this new answer provides compared to the existing one.

Comment: previous answer doesn't compile this onr does :)

Comment: That's why we have the capability of making edits to existing answers. It's been edited.

Comment: great! but since Im a new user I cannot comment on previous answer neither edit it..

Comment: Unfortunately this answer no longer compiles.  Please update it or delete it.

Answer (score 4):

Be aware that [hyper](https://crates.io/crates/hyper) has lots of dependencies and [reqwest](https://crates.io/crates/reqwest) not only depends on `hyper` but also brings quite a few additional dependencies. This may or may not be an issue for you, but it's something you should be aware of.

An alternative you might want to consider is [minreq](https://crates.io/crates/minreq). That crate has only 1 dependency by default (the [log](https://crates.io/crates/log) crate) and a few more that depend on optional features. For example, if you activate the `https-native` feature, it will also add [native-tls](https://crates.io/crates/native-tls) as a dependency.

Here is an example of a simple GET request with [minreq](https://crates.io/crates/minreq) that I copied from their [docs](https://docs.rs/minreq/2.11.0/minreq/):

```
let response = minreq::get("http://example.com").send()?;
assert!(response.as_str()?.contains("</html>"));
assert_eq!(200, response.status_code);
```

Comment: Can you please add an example to support your answer?

Comment: @Brandon Sure, I added an example from their [docs](https://docs.rs/minreq/2.11.0/minreq/). In there one can also find examples of how to send/get headers, send a POST request with a body, set a timeout, etc.