# How can I perform parallel asynchronous HTTP GET requests with reqwest?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, reqwest

[The async example](https://github.com/seanmonstar/reqwest/blob/a4f5c2d3f0a187daa3940d0a249f4748cd38fe0f/examples/async.rs) is useful, but being new to Rust and Tokio, I am struggling to work out how to do N requests at once, using URLs from a vector, and creating an iterator of the response HTML for each URL as a string.

How could this be done?

Answer (score 167, accepted):

## Concurrent requests

As of reqwest 0.11.14:

```rust
use futures::{stream, StreamExt}; // 0.3.27
use reqwest::Client; // 0.11.14
use tokio; // 1.26.0, features = ["macros"]

const CONCURRENT_REQUESTS: usize = 2;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let client = Client::new();

    let urls = vec!["https://api.ipify.org"; 2];

    let bodies = stream::iter(urls)
        .map(|url| {
            let client = &client;
            async move {
                let resp = client.get(url).send().await?;
                resp.bytes().await
            }
        })
        .buffer_unordered(CONCURRENT_REQUESTS);

    bodies
        .for_each(|b| async {
            match b {
                Ok(b) => println!("Got {} bytes", b.len()),
                Err(e) => eprintln!("Got an error: {}", e),
            }
        })
        .await;
}
```

---

> ```
> stream::iter(urls)
> ```

[`stream::iter`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.1/futures/stream/fn.iter.html)

Take a collection of strings and convert it into a [`Stream`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.1/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html).

> ```
> .map(|url| {
> ```

[`StreamExt::map`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.1/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.map)

Run an asynchronous function on every element in the stream and transform the element to a new type.

> ```
> let client = &client;
> async move {
> ```

Take an explicit reference to the `Client` and move the reference (not the original `Client`) into an anonymous asynchronous block.

> ```
> let resp = client.get(url).send().await?;
> ```

Start an asynchronous GET request using the `Client`'s connection pool and wait for the request.

> ```
> resp.bytes().await
> ```

Request and wait for the bytes of the response.

> ```
> .buffer_unordered(N);
> ```

[`StreamExt::buffer_unordered`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.1/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.buffer_unordered)

Convert a stream of futures into a stream of those future's values, executing the futures concurrently.

> ```
> bodies
>     .for_each(|b| {
>         async {
>             match b {
>                 Ok(b) => println!("Got {} bytes", b.len()),
>                 Err(e) => eprintln!("Got an error: {}", e),
>             }
>         }
>     })
>     .await;
> ```

[`StreamExt::for_each`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.29/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#method.for_each)

Convert the stream back into a single future, printing out the amount of data received along the way, then wait for the future to complete.

See also:

- [Join futures with limited concurrency](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43247212/155423)
- [How to merge iterator of streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48785894/155423)
- [How do I synchronously return a value calculated in an asynchronous Future?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52521201/155423)
- [What is the difference between `then`, `and_then` and `or_else` in Rust futures?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55552413/155423)

### Without bounded execution

If you wanted to, you could also convert an iterator into an iterator of futures and use [`future::join_all`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.4/futures/future/fn.join_all.html):

```
use futures::future; // 0.3.4
use reqwest::Client; // 0.10.1
use tokio; // 0.2.11

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let client = Client::new();

    let urls = vec!["https://api.ipify.org"; 2];

    let bodies = future::join_all(urls.into_iter().map(|url| {
        let client = &client;
        async move {
            let resp = client.get(url).send().await?;
            resp.bytes().await
        }
    }))
    .await;

    for b in bodies {
        match b {
            Ok(b) => println!("Got {} bytes", b.len()),
            Err(e) => eprintln!("Got an error: {}", e),
        }
    }
}
```

I'd encourage using the first example as you usually want to limit the concurrency, which `buffer` and `buffer_unordered` help with.

## Parallel requests

Concurrent requests are generally good enough, but there are times where you **need** parallel requests. In that case, you need to spawn a task.

```
use futures::{stream, StreamExt}; // 0.3.8
use reqwest::Client; // 0.10.9
use tokio; // 0.2.24, features = ["macros"]

const PARALLEL_REQUESTS: usize = 2;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let urls = vec!["https://api.ipify.org"; 2];

    let client = Client::new();

    let bodies = stream::iter(urls)
        .map(|url| {
            let client = client.clone();
            tokio::spawn(async move {
                let resp = client.get(url).send().await?;
                resp.bytes().await
            })
        })
        .buffer_unordered(PARALLEL_REQUESTS);

    bodies
        .for_each(|b| async {
            match b {
                Ok(Ok(b)) => println!("Got {} bytes", b.len()),
                Ok(Err(e)) => eprintln!("Got a reqwest::Error: {}", e),
                Err(e) => eprintln!("Got a tokio::JoinError: {}", e),
            }
        })
        .await;
}
```

The primary differences are:

- We use [`tokio::spawn`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.24/tokio/fn.spawn.html) to perform work in separate *tasks*.
- We have to give each task its own `reqwest::Client`. As [recommended](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.10.9/reqwest/struct.Client.html), we clone a shared client to make use of the connection pool.
- There's an additional error case when the task cannot be joined.

See also:

- [What is the difference between concurrent programming and parallel programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1897993/155423)
- [What is the difference between concurrency and parallelism?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1050222/155423)
- [What is the difference between concurrency, parallelism and asynchronous methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4844637/155423)

Comment: Why did you use ` stream::iter_ok(urls).map(..)` ? The closure passed to `.map()` returns a future? We should be using `and_then`?

Comment: Or alternatively, when to use `.map()` and when to use `.and_then()` .. both for stream? and for future?

Comment: @Nawaz See the documentation for [`Stream::buffer_unordered`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.21/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#method.buffer_unordered): *If this stream's item can be converted into a future*. See also [What is the difference between `then`, `and_then` and `or_else` in Rust futures?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55552413/155423)

Comment: Thanks. I read that. I understand that. The `.map()` part is missing though.. Also, how does that translate to `stream` (not `future`).  In case of `stream`, `and_then` is invoked for each _successful_ item in the stream.

Comment: _Convert a stream of futures into a stream of those future's values, executing the futures in parallel._..What if I want `stream of stream of futures`? I've `HaspMap<K, Vec<Url>>` and I want to fetch each `Url`.. and eventually want `HashMap<K, Vec<SomeObject>>`

Comment: I'm trying something like this: `iter_ok(url_map).map(|k, urls| (k, iter_ok(urls).map(..))).buffered_unordered(N).... <lost here>`

Comment: @Nawaz please produce a [MRE] then post a new question, linking to this one and describing why it's different. Try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then include all of that information to reproduce it in your question, such as versions. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here.

Comment: Is there a reason a stream is used rather than joining a list of futures?

Comment: @jpsalm `StreamExt` has the `buffer` and `buffer_unordered` methods, which you'll almost always want to use to prevent completely unbounded requests from taking up all of your system resources (e.g. open sockets). [You don't need it though](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2a3dcc64380f21e51b063f1c5ed82c2b)

Comment: I think this example won't run parallel but only concurrent, based on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/lu4nm3/b8bca9431cdcf19d73040ada13387e58) which I found in [this post](http://patshaughnessy.net/2020/1/20/downloading-100000-files-using-async-rust).

Comment: @AlexMoore-Niemi fair enough. Updated.

Comment: Question - can we clone a single client instead of giving each task its own client?

Comment: @MarkLodato I not sure I follow. When you clone a client you make another client, which you then give to each task as it's own. The only difference is how the unique client is created. So I think the answer is "yes".

Comment: @Shepmaster I'm probably assuming too much but it looks like Client has an inner Arc. Would that imply that cloning it would clone the Arc and allow you to reuse the connection pool (or some wizardry) from the underlying ClientRef?

Comment: @MarkLodato yes, that’s what [the documentation recommends](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.10.9/reqwest/struct.Client.html): *The Client holds a connection pool internally, so it is advised that you create one and reuse it.

You do not have to wrap the Client it in an Rc or Arc to reuse it, because it already uses an Arc internally.*

Comment: @Shepmaster Makes sense! Is there any value in updating this answer to using `clone` instead of `new`ing up for improved copy-ability?

Comment: @MarkLodato ah, now I see why you were asking! Yes, I've addressed that.

Comment: @Shepmaster which of these approaches uses the M:N threading I keep reading so much about? i.e. where the tokio runtime will create concurrent threads but also create parallel threads where necessary

Comment: @Dragoon the one under *Parallel requests*. `tokio::spawn` creates new tasks, and tasks can be moved across threads (when Tokio is using a [multithreaded scheduler](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.2.0/tokio/runtime/index.html#multi-thread-scheduler))

Comment: In case if you need to convert the whole thing into a vector, use `bodies.collect::<Vec<_>>().await`.

Answer (score -2):

If possible for your problem I recommend using std async and rayon. They are both mature now and really easy to get started with given the async{/*  code here  */} scope bounds in std. You can also work into/alongside tokio with feature integration https://docs.rs/async-std/1.10.0/async_std/#features