# How to save a file downloaded from S3 with Rusoto to my hard drive?

Tags: file, amazon-s3, rust, file-transfer, rusoto

I am trying to download a file from a bucket with Rusoto and I am getting the file content:

```
fn get_object(client: &TestClient, bucket: &str, filename: &str) {
    let get_req = GetObjectRequest {
        bucket: bucket.to_owned(),
        key: filename.to_owned(),
        ..Default::default()
    };

    let result = client.get_object(&get_req).sync().expect("Couldn't GET object");


    let stream = result.body.unwrap();
    let body = stream.concat2().wait().unwrap();

    assert!(body.len() > 0);
}
```

How can I save this `GetObjectOutput(result)` object to a file?

Comment: I don't see any `GetObjectOutput`

Comment: @hellow result variable type is GetObjectOutput which I shown in debugger

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there. Your code will put the object in `body`, which is a `Vec<u8>`.

To write the contents of `body` to a file:

```
use std::io::Write;
use std::fs::File;

let mut file = File::create("/path/to/my-object").expect("create failed");
file.write_all(&body).expect("failed to write body");
```

Answer (score 14):

Rusoto now uses the standard library futures and no longer offers the `sync` method, so the previous answer is no longer valid.

## Reading to memory

```
use futures::stream::TryStreamExt;
use rusoto_core::Region;
use rusoto_s3::{GetObjectRequest, S3Client, S3};

type Error = Box<dyn std::error::Error>;
type Result<T, E = Error> = std::result::Result<T, E>;

const BUCKET_NAME: &str = "my very own bucket name";

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let client = S3Client::new(Region::UsEast2);

    let mut object = client
        .get_object(GetObjectRequest {
            bucket: BUCKET_NAME.into(),
            ..Default::default()
        })
        .await?;

    let body = object.body.take().expect("The object has no body");

    let body = body.map_ok(|b| b.to_vec()).try_concat().await?;
    println!("body length: {}", body.len());

    Ok(())
}
```

`AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` need to be specified. I chose to set environment variables outside of the code.

## Streaming to a file

```
use rusoto_core::Region;
use rusoto_s3::{GetObjectRequest, S3Client, S3};
use tokio::{fs::File, io};

type Error = Box<dyn std::error::Error>;
type Result<T, E = Error> = std::result::Result<T, E>;

const BUCKET_NAME: &str = "my very own bucket name";

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let client = S3Client::new(Region::UsEast2);

    let mut object = client
        .get_object(GetObjectRequest {
            bucket: BUCKET_NAME.into(),
            ..Default::default()
        })
        .await?;

    let body = object.body.take().expect("The object has no body");

    let mut body = body.into_async_read();
    let mut file = File::create("/tmp/a-place-to-write").await?;
    io::copy(&mut body, &mut file).await?;

    Ok(())
}
```

While `ByteStream` has an alluring [`into_blocking_read`](https://docs.rs/rusoto_core/0.43.0/rusoto_core/struct.ByteStream.html#method.into_blocking_read) method, I do not recommend using it. If you attempt to use it inside of an async context, you get a panic because it starts a nested Tokio executor. If you use it outside of an async context, it will [truncate the data](https://github.com/rusoto/rusoto/issues/1726) unless you take great care to have the async runtime around but not to be *within* it.

See also:

- [Writing a chunk stream to a file asynchronously using hyper](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53330556/155423)
- [How do I write a futures::Stream to disk without storing it entirely in memory first?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53245412/155423)

## Dependency versions

```
[dependencies]
rusoto_s3 = "0.43.0"
rusoto_core = "0.43.0"
tokio = { version = "0.2.21", features = ["macros"] }
futures = "0.3.5"
```

Comment: In this case should I pick your answer to note it is the correct one from now on?

Comment: @Websterix you should accept the answer that helped **you** the most, and upvote any answers that provide value.

Comment: Does anyone have an example which shows concurrent streams downloading (1:1) to files using the above?

Comment: @BrianBruggeman see [How can I perform parallel asynchronous HTTP GET requests with reqwest?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51044467/155423) for the general structure of such a thing.

Comment: @Shepmaster I think what you show here is good; does this imply that I can use multiple get object futures in place of urls?

Comment: @BrianBruggeman I'd expect something like that, yes.

Comment: Couldn’t manage to put the async version to work, do you have a working version on GitHub or something?