# Return anything in async move block

Tags: rust, closures

So I implmented [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51047786/9934156) code-example and changed it up a little. It now looks like this:

```
pub async fn loadAllSNPData(&mut self, client: &Client) {


let bodies = stream::iter(&self.snps)
    .map(|snp|  {

        let url = format!("https://ncbi.gov/?db=snp&id={}",snp.identifier);

        let client = &client;

        async move {

            let resp = client.get(&url).send().await?;
            let rawJson = resp.text().await;



            // parse json
            let json: Value = serde_json::from_str(&rawJson).expect("JSON was not well-formatted");
            
            Ok((json,snp))
        }

    })
    .buffer_unordered(PARALLEL_REQUESTS);

bodies
    .for_each(|b| {
        async {

            match b {
                Ok(b) => println!("Got {} bytes", b),
                Err(e) => eprintln!("Got an error: {}", e),
            }
        }
    })
    .await;

}
```

It was all working fine until I wanted to return something different than the `rawJson`-Variable containing the text. I want to return the parsed json and the according snp-element to another function that then filters some information from the JSON-Object and stored it inside the corresponding snp-Object. But whenever I change the object that gets returned I get the following error:

> error[E0277]: the `?` operator can only be used in an async block that
> returns `Result` or `Option`...

It then continues to mark the entire `async move`-Block as the origin of the error. How would I go about this to return different things?

Edit: I now return Ok((json,snp)) and get

> error[E0698]: type inside `async fn` body must be known in this
> context

```
Ok((json,snp))
^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `E` declared on
the enum `Result`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error states, you can only use `?` if the return value of the `async` block is a `Result` or `Option`. The type of `rawJson` is a `Result<String>` so when you return it, it works correctly. However, you are trying to return a tuple now, so it complains that you can't use `?` anymore. The solution to this would be to return `Ok((json, snp))` instead.

Comment: Makes sense, but there is still something in my way. If I return Ok((json,snp)) I get `error[E0698]: type inside async fn body must be known in this context` and `cannot infer type for type parameter E declared on the enum Result` points to the `Ok`

Comment: Hmm, does explicitly specifying the type of the `snp` argument help?

Comment: Actually, I think the issue is that it can't infer the type of the error in the returned result. You could solve this by returning `Ok((json, snp)) as reqwest::Result<_>`.

Comment: That was nearly it! `Ok((json,snp)) as reqwest::Result<(_,_)>` is a pretty general solution that worked for me.