# Cannot use filter_map with buffer_unordered when concurrently executing tasks?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm looking at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51044467/how-can-i-perform-parallel-asynchronous-http-get-requests-with-reqwest/51047786#51047786) for concurrently downloading things in Rust.

Roughly, it looks like this:

```rust
#![feature(async_closure)]

use futures::{stream, StreamExt}; // 0.3.13

async fn foo() {
    let xs_new = stream::once(async { 42 })
        .map(async move |x| {
            Some(x + 1)
        })
        .buffer_unordered(42);
}
```

However, I was hoping to use `filter_map` to do something like this:

```rust
#![feature(async_closure)]

use futures::{stream, StreamExt}; // 0.3.13

async fn foo() {
    let xs_new = stream::once(async { 42 })
        .filter_map(async move |x| if x % 2 == 0 { Some(x + 1) } else { None })
        .buffer_unordered(42);
}
```

However this fails with the error: "{integer} is not a Future the trait ... is not implemented for {integer}".

Does anyone know why `filter_map` fails but `map` works fine?

Comment: Try wrapping the `Option` with `futures::future::ready( Some( x + 1 ) )`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`buffer_unordered`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.13/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.buffer_unordered) requires the `Item`s of the `Stream` to themselves be `Future`s. Using [`map`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.13/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.map) with an `async` closure works because it transforms the integers to `Future`s yielding an integer.

Using [`filter_map`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.13/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.filter_map) requires returning a `Future` that yields an `Option` determining whether to filter or not. However, you've forgotten to transform the integers into `Future`s by making it return `Some(Future)`:

```
async fn foo() {
    let xs_new = stream::once(async { 42 })
        .filter_map(async move |x| {
            if x % 2 == 0 {
                Some(async move { x + 1 }) // <--------
            } else {
                None
            }
        })
        .buffer_unordered(42);
}
```